Does $\arg\min_{x \in C}g(x) = P_C (\arg \min_{x}g(x))$?
Let $C$ be a convex set, $g(x)$ a convex  function, and $P_C(x)$ is the projection map onto $C$. Is the following statement true?
$$\arg\min_{x \in C}g(x) = P_C (\arg \min_{x}g(x))$$ If the statement is incorrect, does it become true if $g(x)$ is strongly convex?

no to both, sorry

unless you are in dimension 1

@Exodd Could you please give me some counter examples for dimension >1?

$g(x,y) = x^2 + 2y^2$, $C = {(x,y) : (x-1)^2 + (y-1)^2 \le 1}$. The minimum of $g$ is at $x=y=0$ that projected onto $C$ gives $x=y=1-1/\sqrt 2$.
The minimum of $g$ inside $C$  instead solves $x + m(x-1) = 0$, $2y + m(y-1) = 0$ and $ (x-1)^2 + (y-1)^2 = 1$, where $m$ is the Lagrange multiplier, but if you impose $x=y$ then you find a contradiction

@Exodd Thank you very much for your patient answer!
